# about brackets in NASM's listing file

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am trying to understand how assembling and linking work, so i have a listing file generated using NASM , and I am wandering about meaning of the brackets([]), it's a way to tell that this its a realocateble address that may change in the linking phase?

Edit:I am getting this .lst file using `nasm -f obj`

```
     1                                  segment data public
     2 00000000 4141414141414141            db 8 dup ('A')
     3                                  segment code public
     4                                  ..start:
     5 00000000 B8[ssss]                    mov ax,data
     6 00000003 B8[0300]                    mov ax,$
     7 00000006 B8[0000]                    mov ax,..start
     8 00000009 B80002                      mov ax,200h
     9 0000000C EBFE                        jmp $
```

Comment: IIRC it's around memory addresses, even if they're being used as immediates like in your instruction.  (An address being something that originally depended on the `org` directive in a flat binary).  Note that NASM can make listings when assembling into object files with relocations, where the address is just a placeholder.  So probably anything that would get a relocation entry if assembling into a `-felf32` output?

Comment: @PeterCordes yes i am getting this .lst file using ```nasm -f obj``` ,so the values in the brackets are just a placeholders for the actual true address that we will get in the the link stage.  if i understand correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NASM decorates relocatable values in the listing dump with square brackets **[ ]** or with parenthesis **( )**. This generally signalizes that the value in brackets may differ from the value in linked program, which can be seen in debugger at run-time.
Assembler does not know how will be code and data from other, separately assembled modules, concatenated together at link-time. Neither it cannot know the address where the code and data will be loaded at run-time, so it assumes that all segments start at address **0**. Absolute relocation (marked by **[ ]**) specifies that the value in brackets (offset) requires increase to match the final address at run-time.

In your 16bits example this difference applies only if your program will be linked with some other module which also defines `segment code public`, and if this other module goes first, thus elevating assembled  offsets in your `code` segment. Otherwise offsets at lines 6 and 7 are valid after link-time and those instructions will be encoded as `B80300` and `B80000` in the final executable (no relocations will apply).

Instructions `JMPN` and `CALLN` encode the target address relative to the address of the following instruction (which is kept in *instruction pointer register*), so called **RIP-relative addressing**. When the NEAR `JMP` or `CALL` is performed withing the same segment, assembler is able to calculate the difference immediately and no relocation is requested. However, we may also call some procedure from other, separately assembled module. Although this procedure might lie in the `segment code public`, too, which will be linked together with the main `code` segment, assembler doesn't know the final layout of segments, so it must expend **relative relocation** request, and decorates the immediate value in encoding of `CALLN` with parenthesis **( )**.

Line 5 is a different beast: it encodes **segment address** of the first byte of `data` segment rather than its offset. Thats why NASM displays the paragraph address with `[ssss]` instead of `[0000]` and this value will be definitely other than zero - it depends on the address where DOS will load the executable program.
Initialization of segment registers with `mov ax,data`, `mov ds,ax` is not the only case when segment relocation is necessary, it is used in encoding of every `JMPF` and `CALLF` instruction. Far pointers to the segment part of `JMPF` and `CALLF` encoding are gathered in DOS executable file right after the MZ header (so called **relocation entries**) and they are used **to modify** the segment part of FAR instructions and of stored FAR pointers **at load-time**.

Other assemblers may signalize relocations in listing differently,
for instance [€ASM](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#DumpDecoration) uses **[ ]**, **( )** and **{ }** to distinguish absolute, RIP-relative and segment-address relocations.

Comment: can u explain more about the difference between absolute location relative relocation

Comment: @HestiaGaia See my extended answer above.